# How to make "future" from an array in Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

Have following code:

```
router.get("/fetchOngoingReleases", String.parameter) { (request) -> Future<[ReleaseWithUser]> in
    return Release.query(on: request).filter(\.inProgress == true).all().flatMap { (ra) -> EventLoopFuture<[ReleaseWithUser]> in
        let userId = try request.parameters.next(String.self)
        return User.query(on: request).filter(\.fbId == userId).first().flatMap { (user) -> EventLoopFuture<[ReleaseWithUser]> in
            let a = ra.map { (r) -> ReleaseWithUser in
                // some condition and logic here
            }

            return a. //need this to make future
        }
    }
}
```

I checked all the possible method calls but none of converts `[ReleaseWithUser]` to `Future<[ReleaseWithUser]>`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This `.join(\ReleaseUser.id, to: \Release.id, method: .left)` looks wrong. Should you be joining a primary key to a foreign key rather than another primary?

Comment: What happens if you make releaseId and userId optional in your ReleaseUser model?

Comment: Why have you completely changed this question from the original one? Would it not be better to ask a different question in a different question!!!

Comment: Sorry. I do not know how to handle the 50 question in 30 day limit. I often reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution is:

```
ra.map { (r) -> ReleaseWithUser in
// some condition and logic here
}.flatten(on: request)
```

Array can be converted to future array with `flatten()`.